# how to select circle automatically on image with mouse and crop it using python with open cv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to select a circular part of an image automatically using the mouse and then crop and save it, how can I do that using open cv

Comment: Welcome to SO! Lots of assumptions here; what have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. perhaps you're really looking for [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/docs/) which supports some scripting or [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html) which simplifies interacting with a pointing device like a mouse

Answer (score 0):

Here is the following code for cropping images using a mouse.

```
import cv2 
cropping = False

x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0, 0, 0, 0

image = cv2.imread('normal_face1624.jpg')
oriImage = image.copy()


def mouse_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
        cropping = True

    # Mouse is Moving
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if cropping == True:
            x_end, y_end = x, y

    # if the left mouse button was released
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # record the ending (x, y) coordinates
        x_end, y_end = x, y
        cropping = False # cropping is finished

        refPoint = [(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end)]

        if len(refPoint) == 2: #when two points were found
            roi = oriImage[refPoint[0][1]:refPoint[1][1], refPoint[0][0]:refPoint[1][0]]
            cv2.imwrite('crop_image.png', roi)
            cv2.imshow("Cropped", roi)


cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", mouse_crop)

while True:

    i = image.copy()

    if not cropping:
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

    elif cropping:
        cv2.rectangle(i, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", i)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanx for your answer this code is work for rectangle selection can I do it with circle??